# Is it possible to import a normal Kotlin library into Kotlin Mutliplatform Mobile

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

Is there a way to import a normal Kotlin Library (*with only data classes*) into a multiplatform project. If yes please provide source :)

**OR**

Must I use the Kotlin Multiplatform Library Template to provide simple information.

I want to import it into all parts of KMM (Common, Android, ...). As I want to use the library in a Spring Boot (Kotlin) backend too, I thought using KMM Library would not work there.

Thankful for any help!

Comment: What do you mean by normal here? If it's .jar, then the answer is definitely no. If it's a multiplatform library published with all the information about platforms, then yes, one can use it with any platform it was published for. For more info about publishing libraries like that, see [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-publish-lib.html)

Comment: yeah with normal I meant a JAR. Is there a way to use the multplatform library in a plain Kotlin application (i.e. console -> use common code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jar` is JVM specific, so you could use it in your Kotlin/JVM part, not in common/shared code.

For sharing DTOs you could look at this example: https://github.com/halcyonmobile/MultiplatformPlayground#module-hierarchy

where `commonModel` shares keys and DTOs between a JVM backend and a KMM common code

Comment: Thank you. Had some issues while trying out. Ended up copying your gradle file - then it worked. So the gradle file from the template is not working when you want to import it into another module.